# Calling a button event without postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a button that I want to function like normal, except I don't want it to postback.

If a user clicks it, I want to execute the Button Click event on the next postback, I just don't want that particular button to be able to postback.

I tried this:

```
<asp:Button ID="ChangeAllBtn" runat="server" Text="Change All" OnClientClick="return false;" OnClick="ChangeAllBtnClick" />
```

But it doesn't call the ChangeAllBtnClick after I postback.
If I remove the "return false;", then there is postback before I want it.

What do?

Comment: why do you want to submit on 2nd and not first click? `return false;` will stop processing and `onclick` event will not fire. Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I have a button that's just doing a client side script so I disable postback. However I would like to know on the server side if it has been clicked at some point so I can change some functionality of my program.

Comment: add return true or false in your script and it will not call onclick until your client script is executed ex: `OnCLientClick="return javascript_function();"`

Comment: @rs, isn't that what he's doing now?

Comment: yes but he is not returning true, he is using `return false;` which will stop form processing. If he returns true/false based on that onclick event will be fired.

Comment: I don't think he wants to post back though.  The question title is a bit confusing.

Comment: @rs. I tried changing it to true, but it just postbacks the page when I click it. And it still doesn't call the server event when it is return false

Comment: @proseidon postback event will not be fired when you do return false; your question is very confusing and not clear.

Comment: I basically want the button to function like a TextChanged event with AutoPostBack=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like an odd request.  I'm not sure how to do it off the top of my head.  Would it be possible to structure your code in such a way that when you post back it just executes the code that would have been in your button click event?  Example:

```
void ChangeAllBtnClick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
   DoStuff();
}

void RealButton_BtnClick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
   DoStuff(); //Executing all the code that would have been run for ChangeAllBtnClick here
   /*
      code for RealButton would be in here...
   */
}

void DoStuff()
{
   //Whatever
}
```

If that's not an option I would probably create a hidden field that is a server side control.  Then you can set this from the client side script and check the value on the server side.

Comment: Unfortunately no. The specifics are that I'm doing a huge database management page. There are a lot of controls going on, some individual, some mass changes. Some of my buttons allow a user to mass-edit columns. I don't want the page to postback until they are done with their changes, but if they click the 'change all' buttons I'd like to know, because then I pre-load the database for faster accessing; if it's small changes then pre-loading it is unneccesary.

Comment: where do you pre-load your database? You can call a webservice onclient click and based on changes you can decide to either pre load database and after that script is processed onclick postback can then check status and process data

Answer (score 2):

You can have a hidden field that stores the first click. If the user is clicking the second time you can try to make a ajax request ..

This way there will not be a postback in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Will the following work? Set the onclientclick javascript to return false so it doesn't postback, but also have that function set a value in a hidden field to "1",the default being "0"  basically a flag.

On the PageLoad check the value of the hidden field, if the value is one, then execute the desired code and set the hidden field value back to 0.

```
<!------HTML Code------>
<input type="hidden" id="hdnChangeAllFlag  value="0" />
<asp:Button ID="ChangeAllBtn" runat="server" Text="Change All" OnClientClick="return > ChangeAllClicked()" />

<script>
function ChangeAllClicked()
{
$("#hdnChangeAllFlag").val('1');
return false;
}
</script>
''' Server Side Code

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Request("hdnChangeAllFlag")="1" and IsPostback Then
        ''''Y
    End If

End Sub
```